# Retriving image from firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I can't retrieve an image or name from firebase. How can I retrieve my image from firebase storage?

```
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}
    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.1.0:455)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.1.0:435)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.1.0:426)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.1.0:280)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.1.0:294)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.1.0:65)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.1.0:57)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.1.0:71)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

Answer (score 2):

retrieve your image from firebase storeage :-

```
StorageReference ref = mImageStorage.child("image table name")
                    .child("image name"+ ".jpg");

    ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Uri downUri = task.getResult();
                                String imageUrl = downUri.toString();
                                // now you can use imageUrl anywhere you want
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: StorageReference does not have `addOnCompleteListener`

instead you can use `ref.getDownloadUrl()#addOnCompleteListener()`